# Sendmail won't send email to same domain

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web-server, sendmail

I have seen many references to this problem on server fault and all over the internet, but none of the solutions has fixed my problem.

I am running Sendmail 8.14.4 on Ubuntu 13.10, this is a webserver only (call it `domain.com`) and handles no incoming or outgoing email other than to send out automated messages to users via php `mail()`. Any incoming mail to `someone@domain.com` is handled via a different server setup through an MX record and works as expected. As seems to be a frequent problem any email sent from the server to `someone@domain.com` is locally routed and fails, but any other domain works as expected.

I have tried numerous solutions including adding `` define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES',  `True')dnl `` to `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`, then running `sendmailconfig` and restarting sendmail. However, it does not fix the issue and on running the command `echo $=w | sendmail -bt` `domain.com` still appears in the list. I have removed `domain.com` from `/etc/mail/local-host-names`, but is there anywhere else I need to remove it? Do I need to remove any references in `/etc/hosts`? When I run `hostname` `domain.com` is reported, can I change this and if I did would it cause problems with any other services?

Giving up on this solution I also tried to set up a relay by adding the following to `sendmail.mc`:

```
define(`MAIL_HUB', `example.com.')dnl
define(`LOCAL_RELAY', `example.com.')dnl
```

However, this has also failed to fix the problem. What am I missing? I would prefer to have the email sent straight from the server if possible rather than relaying it, but at this stage any solution would be good!

Update:
I have now changed the hostname to `www.domain.com` and it seems to now be hitting the mailserver correctly rather than routing locally. However I'm now getting an error saying unknown user? The mailserver has a forwarding account set up for that specific user although no actual mail box, is this a problem? I have added the log below:

```
Jan 27 12:13:31 www sendmail[1839]: s0RCDV3n001839: from=www-data, size=129, class=0, nrcpts=2, msgid=<201401271213.s0RCDV3n001839@www.domain.com>, relay=www-data@localhost
Jan 27 12:13:32 www sm-mta[1841]: s0RCDVtW001841: from=<www-data@www.domain.com>, size=401, class=0, nrcpts=2, msgid=<201401271213.s0RCDV3n001839@www.domain.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Jan 27 12:13:32 www sendmail[1839]: s0RCDV3n001839: to=someone@domain.com,someone@anotherdomain.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=60129, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s0RCDVtW001841 Message accepted for delivery)
Jan 27 12:13:32 www sm-mta[1843]: STARTTLS=client, relay=spool.mail.gandi.net., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Jan 27 12:13:36 www sm-mta[1843]: s0RCDVtW001841: to=<someone@anotherdomain.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@www.domain.com> (33/33), delay=00:00:05, xdelay=00:00:04, mailer=esmtp, pri=150401, relay=spool.mail.gandi.net. [217.70.184.6], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as 378B22A89BC)
Jan 27 12:13:36 www sm-mta[1843]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mail.domain.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Jan 27 12:13:36 www sm-mta[1843]: s0RCDVtW001841: to=<someone@domain.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@www.domain.com> (33/33), delay=00:00:05, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=150401, relay=mail.domain.com. [79.170.40.74], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Jan 27 12:13:36 www sm-mta[1843]: s0RCDVtW001841: s0RCDatW001843: DSN: User unknown
Jan 27 12:13:37 www sm-mta[1843]: s0RCDatW001843: to=<www-data@www.domain.com>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

I have tested the user via a telnet connection to the mailserver and the user was accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your server should have a (FQDN) hostname other than domain.com. 
  After that check sendmail configuration for LOCAL_DOMAIN settings. Remove 'domain.com' entries if you have and have only localhost and the FQDN.

Dont forget to recompile sendmails configs after changing the .mc files.

Bests,
Semir

Comment: Thank you, this does seem to have made sendmail check the MX record rather than routing locally, although I'm now getting an Unknown user error, please see the updated question.

Comment: check all your domain settings (have valid PTR for eg).

Comment: @blask That's a different issue entirely. Please don't put separate issues in the same question after it was answered.

Comment: @MichaelHampton fair point, I have asked another question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/570170/sendmail-user-unknown-error-when-sending-to-remote-server